# Django - acces image from image field in the template

Tags: django, django-file-upload, django-media

What I have done:
in `models.py`:

```
class Image(models.Model):
  img = models.ImageField(blank=True, Null=True)
```

And now I want to acces the image in the template. I tried it, but it didn't work: (`myimg` is an instance of `Image`.)

```
<img src="{{ myimg.img }}">
```

So: How do I acces the image from the template?

---

Another thing: when I used my model like that the images where stored at the projects root. This doesn't seem to be a good idea. Where should they be stored? And how do I store them somewhere else.

---

Some other little questions which deal with that problem:

- What is `MEDIA_URL` good for and how does it work?
- What is `MEDIA_ROOT` good for and how does it work?
- Where should files that aren't static (that means files a user or an admin uploads) be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the location where your images are stored. If they are currently being stored at the project root, that is because that's what you have defined as MEDIA_ROOT; don't do that. You can put them wherever makes sense on your system, though.

`MEDIA_URL` is the URL at which your images are served. It's up to you to configure your webserver to do that; Django won't (although it can be made to do it in development mode only.)

To access the URL of an image field in the template, use the `url` property:

```
<img src="{{ myimg.img.url }}">
```